# Recursive function to generate string does not contain two adjacent identical substring c++

Tags: c++, string, function, recursion, substring

I have a task that is difficult for me to handle. The task is: Create recursive function that can be generate a string of length N (N <= 100), formed by the letters 'A', 'B' and 'C' and does not containing two identical adjacent substring. For example: enter for N = 6 and the program should generate such a string in which no one else to repeated substrings: ABACAB. Wrong strings are: **AA**BACA - because 'A' is to 'A'; A**BCBC**A - as 'BC' is to 'BC' and **ABCABC** is also wrong because 'ABC' is to 'ABC'.

I made a version of the program but an iterative way, here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

const char letters[] = "ABC";

char generate_rand()
{

     return letters[rand() % 3];

}

int check(char *s, int pos) 
{

    for (int i = 1; i <= (pos + 1)/2; i++) 
    {

        int flag = 1;

        for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)

        if (s[pos-j] != s[pos-i-j]) 
        {

            flag = 0; 
                break;

        }

        if (flag)
            return 1;

    }
    return 0;
}

int main() 
{

    char s[100];
    int n;

    cout << "enter n: ";
    cin >> n;

    srand(time(NULL));

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) 
    {

        do
        {

            s[i] = generate_rand();

        } while (check(s, i));

        cout << s[i] << " ";

    }

    cout << " ok" << endl;

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

I think the entrance of the recursive function may need to be the number of characters in the string, which will seek to repeat with an adjacent string and each time increased by 1, but not more than half the length of the original string, but do not know how to do it.

Comment: your code does not seem to contain any recursive function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So lets start with a simple recursive function which prints 10 letters but doesn't check anything:

```
void addLetter(char* buf, int max_length)
{
   int len = strlen(buf);
   buf[len] = generate_rand();
   if (strlen(buf) < max_length) 
      addLetter(buf);
}

int main()
{
   srand(time(NULL)); //I forgot srand!
   int max_length = 10; //ask user to input max_length, like you had earlier
   char buf[100];
   memset(buf,0,sizeof(buf));
   addLetter(buf, max_length);
   printf("\n%s\n", buf);
   return 0;
}
```

Now lets change the recursive function, get it to check just 1 letter:

```
void addLetter(char* buf, int max_length)
{
   int len = strlen(buf);
   buf[len] = generate_rand();

   if (len > 0)
   {
      if (buf[len] == buf[len-1])
         buf[len] = 0;
   }

   if (strlen(buf) < max_length) 
      addLetter(buf);
}
```

Next step, check 2 letters with previous ones etc. You should be able to take it from here.

Comment: Can generate string, but each time generating the same characters in pairs. for example CBCBAB perhaps this is due to the function srand ().

Comment: Yes, I forgot srand. Put `srand` back in `main` like you had it before.

Comment: Now works, but sometimes generate identical substrings.

Comment: Yes, it's not checking for that part. You have to finish it yourself. Also I forgot, `n` should be a parameter in `addLetter(char* buf, int n);` or call it `max_length`.